# Check all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, greasemonkey

Is there a greasemonkey script or another way to check all checkboxes of any webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several ways.
but this one is ready :)

Check boxes
http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/6474

Comment: As no instructions are given by author on userscripts.org - usage of this nifty little userscript: once installed, so long as it is enabled in greasemonkey etc., it will scan each new page you refresh from that point on and give a little menu up the top of the page in the center, to check 'All', 'None', or 'Invert'.

Comment: Page is no longer available